# Using TensorFlow how do you get it to give you a prediction given one new set of features?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

How would you go and ask:

I have just collected a new iris specimen from the field.  I have it's Sepal length,Sepal width,Petal length,Petal width.

Please tell me the Species and the accuracy of that prediction.

Starting with this code:

```
import tensorflow.contrib.learn as skflow
from sklearn import datasets, metrics

iris = datasets.load_iris()
classifier = skflow.TensorFlowDNNClassifier(hidden_units=[10, 20, 10], n_classes=3)
classifier.fit(iris.data, iris.target)
score = metrics.accuracy_score(iris.target, classifier.predict(iris.data))
print("Accuracy: %f" % score)
```

Comment: just call predict on a list containing a single element - your new observations. You cannot get an accuracy though, accuracy is a percentage of correct answers, thus you need **a true class** of your new iris. If you do have - you can either get correct prediction (100% accuracy) or wrong (0%), nothing else is possible.

Comment: I think he means the confidence (SoftMax value) of the prediction.  Find the API to the top-1 or top-5 scores; those *should* be normalized scores that translate directly to confidence proportions.

Comment: Given the code above, how would you call predict on a single element and what are it's results. This piece of the puzzle seems to be left out of tutorials.